# Problema de geolocalizacion con google maps

Tags: google-maps

Hace unas semanas mi `api-key` empezó a fallar por lo que decidí renovar para una nueva pero al momento de cambiar mi `api-key` aquí específicamente me manda este error al querer obtener una localización

> nuevo:1406 [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no
>   longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should
>   consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.
>   Seefor more details.

Mi sitio no es `HTTPS` es `HTTP`, pero antes servia a la perfeccion

Comment: Esta API de google fue removida por seguridad para Chrome v50+ Te recomiendo que le pongas un certificado a tu sitio. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: si llegase a tener una version mas baja de chrome funcionaria? o algun otro navegador?

Comment: Posiblemente funcione con una versión mas baja, sin embargo google es muy especial en cuanto a que si te dice que NO es NO y puede que te llegue a bloquear, habría que leer sus Términos de este cambio.
Como lo dice en su anuncio, la ubicación del usuario es un dato sensible que viaja o viajaba sin seguridad.